# Error message with colliding IP address when running "vigrant up" command

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

I am trying to use Vagrant on Windows with with Homestead and VMware Workstation and am receiving the error below:

```
Bringing machine 'homestead' up with 'vmware_workstation' provider...
==> homestead: Checking if box 'laravel/homestead' version '12.0.0' is up to date...
==> homestead: Verifying vmnet devices are healthy...
The host only network with the IP '192.168.56.56' would collide with
another device '100.120.130.1'. This means that VMware cannot create
a proper networking device to route to your VM. Please choose
another IP or shut down the existing device.
```

Any assistance with this would be appreciated. I am unclear how to resolve this problem or what is causing it. I have no other machines running and have tried rebooting my computer. I am also unclear how these IP addresses are colliding?

Many thanks.

Comment: can you share your vagrantfile?

Comment: Sure, here you go: https://pastebin.com/cA1qQqZd

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove and reinstall VMWare. Maybe the issue is related with a cached setting relating to a previous VM or something like that.

I also recommend switching to VirtualBox, but this is only a suggestion.

Comment: Hi, The problem was when installing with VirtualBox. I have installed with VMWare and everything is worknig now. Thanks.